# Track completion of javascript callbacks without nesting functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, closures

So I'm writing a function that makes a bunch of database calls. I want to store their results in an array and trigger a callback once they're all done.

Some pseudocode may help:

```
function getStuff (array, callback) {
    var results = [];
    var done = 0;
    for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
        database.fetchOne(array[i], function(result) {
            results[i] = result;
            done++;
            if (done == len)
                callback(results);
        });
    }
}
```

This works great. However, I'm told it's bad practice to nest a closure inside a loop because it keeps defining the function every iteration, and that comes at a performance cost.

Other answers suggest moving the callback outside of the loop:

```
function getStuff (array, callback) {
    var results = [];
    var done = 0;
    for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
        database.fetchOne(array[i], myCallback.bind(this, i, results, done, callback));
    }
}

function myCallback (i, results, done, callback, result) {
    results[i] = result;
    done++;
    if (done == len)
        callback(results);
}
```

But this doesn't work since `done` has an immutable type, so it doesn't change the value of `done` in `getStuff`.

So... what do I do?

Comment: Just to clarify, `done` is not an immutable type, it's a primitive which is passed by value rather than by reference. It's a fine distinction, but one that I think is important to note.

Comment: What context are you in? is this node.js? You could approach this by using promises and executing a callback when all are done, it should be a more elegant way of handling this.

Comment: @Sosdoc, it doesn't matter. In node.js and client-side JS alike, the same standards for asynchronous callbacks would apply.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I'm asking just for pointing out a possible solution using promises, in case this isn't node (but I doubt it) it could be done by just using jquery.

Comment: @Sosdoc I am in node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the myCallback just once, instead of in every iteration.

```
function getStuff (array, callback) {
    var results = [];
    var done = 0;

    function myCallback(i, callback, result) { 
        // update results and done in here
    }
    for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
        database.fetchOne(array[i], myCallback.bind(this, i, results, done, callback));
    }
}
```

Comment: I would personally globalize `results` to the closure as well rather than passing it to each function if I were to use this method.

Comment: So how do I call `getStuff` when it's inside the anonymous function?

Comment: I just realized actually that would only allow `getStuff` to work once. Perhaps my edit wasn't so elegant.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Maybe if `done` and `results` were defined in the closure, but their values were set in `getStuff`?

Comment: @Cheezey that would be better but would still limit `getStuff` from being called in parallel since `done` and `results` would interfere with each other.

Comment: maybe define myCallback, done and results inside getStuff, but not in the loop?

Comment: @yts Yes that would be a good approach. Instead of being defined for each iteration it would only be defined once for each call to `getStuff`. Go ahead and edit it that way.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That should suffice for now; thank you both for your help! If any more efficient solutions are found, I'm still open to them.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using promises with Q

First of all, install Q with npm

```
npm install q
```

And remember to require it

```
var Q = require('q');
```

then your final code could be this

```
function getStuff (array, callback) {
    //denodeify transforms a node function into one that works with promises
    var fetch = Q.denodeify(database.fetchOne);
    // all waits for all promises to be resolved
    var promise = Q.all(array.map(fetch));

    // callback receives an array with all the return values from fetchOne
    promise.then(callback, function(error) {
        //this gets called in case any of the calls has an error
    });
}
```

This is a more elegant solution in my opinion, I recommend reading up on Q and all its possible usages, it can avoid nasty situations where you have lots of nested callback (often referred as 'callback hell')

Comment: Definitely more elegant. I'll look into it later, thanks!